Can you disable HTTP client cache when using server-side rendering?
I am loading app config in my application using APP_INITIALIZER
It is using the HTTP client to get the config and it's working fine
The problem is when I build and deploy application. The HTTP client is returning cached results
I have added withNoHttpTransferCache to providers like this
provideClientHydration(withNoHttpTransferCache()), but all this does is calling the endpoint twice
First time I still get cached response, and the second time I get the proper response
Is there a way to remove this cache and get the proper response on the first call?

withNoHttpTransferCache() is the way to go, there is no other cache. There must be somthing else in your code.
